# A local variable can be named as yield

Tags: c#, yield-return

Just found out

```
foreach (int yield in items) {
  yield return yield * 2;
}
```

or

```
int yield = 10;
```

are valid codes in C#.

I can understand it could be easy for the compiler to differentiate between a variable yield and an iterator yield, but still it adds to the confusion and lessen the readability of the code.

Do we know the exact reasons why is it allowed?

Comment: I believe, things are other way around. First, rules on variable naming are established, then some keywords are banned from usage. So, there should not be any reason to allow something. Do you know any good reason to reject `yield` as a variable name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Do we know the exact reasons why is it allowed?

Yes. `yield` is only a *contextual* keyword. It was introduced in C# 2, and the team didn't want to break code which already used `yield` as an identifier.

The same is true for other contextual keywords which have been introduced since 1.0, such as `partial`. See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx) for the complete list.

> but still it adds to the confusion and lessen the readability of the code

So don't do that then? There are any number of things you can do to make your code really, really hard to read. You could make all your variable names just underscores:

```
private int _;
private string __;
// etc
```

Do you do that? If not, why would you expect people to write confusing code with `yield` specifically?

Comment: In order to preserve any backward compatibility, shall we consider the list of the keywords in c# as closed?

Comment: Not at all. Some keywords need to be made non-contextual, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: also: partial, dynamic, add, remove, ...? (Although add/remove are 1.0)

Comment: @NileshChauhan: Yes, I think so. I would be surprised to see new "normal" keywords added.

Comment: @MarcGravell: add and remove were already in C# 1. They're contextual keywords, but not new ones. (Ditto value)

Comment: @KendallFrey: I think it *very* unlikely that the C# team would introduce new "real" keywords now. Any term good enough to be a keyword is likely to be in use already in code bases.

Comment: @NileshChauhan The C# team has gone out of their way to ensure that new keywords are added are contextual specifically for backwards compatability reasons.  `yield return` could have been just `yield` as a full keyword, but that would be a breaking change.  They made it contextual to avoid that.  `await` would have been a breaking change if it was alone; `async` was added because with the two together they're both contextual, and there are no breaking changes, unlike if `await` was on it's own.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx for the full list.

Comment: @EricLippert: Duly referenced instead of trying to list them all here :)

Answer (score 2):

`yield` is a contextual keyword. It could be an ordinary keyword, but they chose to make it a contextual keyword.

The main reason for contextual keywords is backwards compatibility. If they added a normal keyword to the language, it might break code that is being copied from older versions of the language.

For example, imagine compiling this code after `yield` was added as a normal keyword:

```
bool yield = false;
// bla bla
```

It wouldn't work very well, would it? You'd have to rename your variables before you could compile it with the newer version.